# Showing that $e^z$, $\sin(z)$, $\cos(z)$ have essential singularities at $\infty$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

> **Problem:** Show that $e^z$, $\sin(z)$, $\cos(z)$ have essential singularities at $\infty$.

**Attempt for $e^z$:**

1. We have that $e^z$ has an essential singularity at $\infty$ iff $e^{1/z}$ has an essential singularity at $0$ iff

   $$
   0 \ne \lim_{z \to 0} |z|^{\alpha} |e^{1/z}| \ne \infty
   $$

   for all values of $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$.

My intuitions must be off here, because it seems to me like $|e^{1/z}|$ tends to infinity much quicker than $|z|^\alpha$ tends to zero.  That is, it seems to me that indeed

$$\lim_{z \to 0} |z|^{\alpha} |e^{1/z}| = \infty$$

which evidently is not the case.

Comment: You've focused on $\lim_{z\rightarrow 0^+}$.  What happens as $z$ goes to zero along the negative real axis?  What happens as $z$ approaches zero from both directions along the imaginary axis?  Does the limit exist?

Comment: I used comments here and below to make what I think is the complete proof below.  Does it look good?

Answer (score 6):

$$
e^z=e^{x+iy}\quad \Big( \text{where }x,y\in\mathbb R \Big) = e^x (\cos y+i\sin y).
$$
So think about what happens as $y\to\infty$ with $x$ fixed.  No limit in $\mathbb C\cup\{\infty\}$ is approached.

Answer (score 5):

$f(z)$ has an essential singularity at $\infty_{\mathbb C}$ iff $f(1/z)$ has an essential singularity in $0$.

Now the Taylor series of $e^z$ (around $z=0$, but it holds on all $\mathbb C$) is
$$
e^z=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{z^n}{n!}
$$
Hence
$$
e^{\frac1{z}}=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac1{z^n n!}
$$
that is the Laurent series for $e^{1/z}$ around $z=0$.
So $c_{-n}\neq0$ for (almost) all $n\in\mathbb N$, that is the definition of essential singularity.

Proceed similarly for $\sin$ and $\cos$.

Comment: I can see that for e and sin and cos the sigularity is essential, but if I divided one of them over the other, how can I a determine the type of the singularity? For example $\frac{e^{\frac{1}{z}}}{sin(\frac{1}{{z)}$

Answer (score 4):

Since we have that

$$
\lim_{z \to 0+} \left|e^{1/z}\right| = \infty
$$

$$
\lim_{z \to 0-} \left|e^{1/z}\right| = 0
$$

it follows that

$$
0 \ne \lim_{z \to 0} |z|^{\alpha} |e^{1/z}| \ne \infty
$$

so that $e^z$ has an essential singularity at $\infty$ by definition.

Furthermore, the definitional dependencies of $\sin(z)$ and $\cos(z)$ on the exponential function means that

$$\cos(z) = {e^{iz} + e^{-iz} \over 2}$$

$$\sin(z) = {e^{iz} - e^{-iz} \over 2i}$$

have essential singularities at $\infty$ if and only if $\exp(z)$ has an essential singularity at $\infty$.  Therefore, both $\cos(z)$ and $\sin(z)$ have essential singularities at $\infty$ as well. This completes the proof.

Comment: Your argument for $\sin$ and $\cos$ depends on the unstated (and unproven) assumption that the singularities in $\exp$ aren't cancelled out in the sum and difference you've written.

Comment: Good point.  This can be dealt with by appealing to the fact that the limit of a sum is the sum of the limits.  Then if I prove that $e^{iz}$ and $e^{-iz}$ have essential singularities at $\infty$, the proof will then be done.  Does this sound reasonable?

Comment: Well, no...  $\mathrm{e}^z$ and $\mathrm{e}^z$ have essential singularities at $0$, but $\mathrm{e}^z - \mathrm{e}^z = 0$ does not.  You need to show that the singularity is *not* cancelled in the addition or subtraction.  (Imprecisely (and really, by analogy), it could be conditionally convergent and still be convergent...)

Comment: @EricTowers Sorry to bother you after so long, but I had exactly your concern and am attempting to work around it. I think writing $\sin x$ as $\dfrac{e^{2iz}+1}{2e^{iz}}$ shows convincingly that the singularities are no cancelled out. How does this sound to you?